# Getting cluster type error on helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Trying to do:

```
helm upgrade --namespace keycloak -f k8s/sandbox/values.yaml keycloak codecentric/keycloak
```

Getting:

```
UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "keycloak-http" with kind Service: Service "keycloak-http" is invalid: [spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP', spec.ports[1].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP']
```

However, initial values *is* NodePort, not ClusterIP:

```
service:
  # Annotations for headless and HTTP Services
  annotations: {}
  # Additional labels for headless and HTTP Services
  labels: {}
  # key: value
  # The Service type
  type: NodePort
```

Also kubectl edit shows type: NodePort

```
spec:
  clusterIP: <SomeIP>
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31062
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31258
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  - name: http-management
    nodePort: 32113
    port: 9990
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http-management
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keycloak
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

Here is the keycloak-http service from `helm template`. For some reason it says ClusterIp, but both the inital values.yaml says NodePort and also kubectl edit service keycloak-http say it is NodePort:

```
# Source: keycloak/templates/service-http.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-http
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: keycloak-10.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keycloak
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "12.0.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: http
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 8443
      targetPort: https
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http-management
      port: 9990
      targetPort: http-management
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: keycloak
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the content of the new values.yaml that you to upgrade with?

Comment: @thomas: Only trying to upgrade the image:
``` 
image:
  # The Keycloak image repository
  repository: <OUR_REPOSITORY>
  # Overrides the Keycloak image tag whose default is the chart version
  tag: staging
  # The Keycloak image pull policy
  pullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Can you generate the template with `helm template` and paste the service part from it?

Comment: @thomas: The `helm template` output was too long for a comment, so I pasted it into the original question. It shows ClusterIP although both the initial values and `kubectl edit` shows NodePort.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the service manually and perform the helm upgrade again

Comment: Tried that, but deleting the service also deleted the load balancer rule. Had to recreate with helm uninstall and helm install. Thanks for suggestion, though

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the repository and tried changing the `values.yaml` to `NodePort` and this works fine for me. The template that was printed had `NodePort` instead of `ClusterIP`. This means that you might be doing something wrong or perhaps using some wrong values file.

Now the error itself is there because you can't change the service type like that and Kubernetes won't allow it because `NodePort` has additional parameter included in the service template:

```json
"ports": [
            {
                "name": "http",
                "nodePort": 30240,
                "port": 8888,
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "targetPort": "http"
            }
```

While this is the ClusterIP:

```json
"ports": [
            {
                "name": "http",
                "port": 8888,
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "targetPort": "http"
            }
```

There are couple of possible workaround for this issue when you attempt to change service like that:

- Install new version of the helm chart with a different release name
- Manually change the service type with `kubectl edit svc`
- Delete the existing release and install new version of the chart with the same release name

Comment: Thank you for helping me on this @thomas. I am using https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/keycloak/values.yaml as base. In the service part I have just changed ClusterIP to NodePort, nothing else. I have changed other parts though, like the Ingress. I understand changing from ClusterIP to NodePort for an existing service is a NoGo this way, but I cannot understand why helm installs a ClusterIP version when I am stating NodePort. I will look more into it this weekend to spot problems in values.yaml and try your suggestions (tried 3 bullet many times though...) .

Comment: Sure. I will give it another go on Monday as well. Weird part is that "dry" generated template has `ClusterIP` instead of the `NodePort`. This part I could not reproduce. Whenever I change it it reflects within the template.

Comment: Strange. Used the bare https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/keycloak/values.yaml changing only ClusterIP to NodePort. Still `helm template` reports ClusterIP for the keycloak-http service. Also when using `kubectl edit svc` the type already is NodePort. It's just `helm template` reporting ClusterIP. And of course (which is my problem) `elm upgrade` thinks the service is ClusterIP (maybe based on an internal helm upgrade during the upgrade?). Maybe I just resort to `helm uninstall`followed by a `helm install`. Would be nice to understand the reason, though...